# Is there a Grails/Groovy way to extract a sublist from a list?

Tags: grails, model-view-controller, groovy

My model:

```
class Fizz {
    String bimder
    Buzz buzz
}

class Buzz {
    int bupo
}
```

In my controller I am maintaining a list of `Fizz` instances:

```
class MyController {
    static List<Fizz> fizzes = []

    def index() {
        render(view: "display_buzzes", model: fizzes)
    }
}
```

In my `display_buzzes.gsp`:

```
<!--
    Here I want to iterate through all the fizzes, extract their buzz
    instance, and inject that buzz into a list to display as an option
    inside this select.
-->
<g:select name="buzzes" from="${???}" />
```

Hence, inside the `<select>`, I want Grails to somehow extract the "sublist" of `Buzz` instances from the `fizzes` list, and display the buzzes. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to solving your issue is using `collect` to collect a list of your `Buzz` instances. Here is a simple Groovy example of how it's used:

```
​class Fizz {
  String bimder
  Buzz buzz
}  
class Buzz { 
  int bupo 
}

List<Fizz> fizzes = [
  new Fizz(bimder: '1', buzz: new Buzz(bupo: 1)), ​​​
  new Fizz(bimder: '2', buzz: new Buzz(bupo: 2)),
  new Fizz(bimder: '3', buzz: new Buzz(bupo: 3)),
  new Fizz(bimder: '4', buzz: new Buzz(bupo: 4))
]

println ​fizzes.collect{it.buzz}​
```

Now in your particular `<g:select>` you will need to use the following:

```
<g:select name="buzzes" from="${fizzes.collect{it.buzz}}" />
```

The above will give you a list of the collected buzzes from your fizzes list. Enjoy!

Answer (score 3):

```
from="${fizzes*.buzz}"
```

should do.

But (*not related to actual question*) the way you have setup your controller is error prone.

Controllers are singleton by default (in newer version of Grails), so

```
static List<Fizz> fizzes = []
```

will always maintain a state across requests. If that is what you do not want, then fetch `Fizz` inside the action method. For example:

```
class MyController {
    def index() {
        List<Fizz> fizzes = Fizz.all
        render( view: "display_buzzes", model: [fizzes: fizzes] )
    }
}
```